# private ArrayAdapter not visible in onLoaderFinished method

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am developing an android and am having trouble with a simple concept.  I can't understand why a private ArrayAdapter to the activity class is not "in scope" in the onLoadFinished method.

I have;

```
public class DestinationListActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    // Sub-Activity static return code identifiers
    private static final int SUBACTIVITY_SINGLEDESTINATION = 1;

    // Create the array list of destinations
    private ArrayList<String> vArrayList_Destinations = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
    private ArrayAdapter<String> vArrayAdapter_Destinations;
```

With the onCreate;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Inflate the view
setContentView(R.layout.destinationlistactivity);

// Set references to the widgets
Button vButton_AddNew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.destinationlistactivity_Button_AddNew);
ListView vListView_DestinationList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.destinationlistactivity_ListView_DestinationList);

// Create the array list of destinations
//ArrayList<String> vArrayList_Destinations = new ArrayList<String>();

// Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
ArrayAdapter<String> vArrayAdapter_Destinations = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         vArrayList_Destinations);

// Bind the array adapter to the list view
vListView_DestinationList.setAdapter(vArrayAdapter_Destinations);

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

and the onLoadFinished of;

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> pLoader, Cursor pCursor)
{
int keyDestinationIndex = pCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DestinationContentProvider.DESTINATION_NAME);

vArrayList_Destinations.clear();
while (pCursor.moveToNext())
{
    vArrayList_Destinations.add(pCursor.getString(keyDestinationIndex));
}
vArrayAdapter_Destinations.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I am debugging, and come to the vArrayAdapter_Destinations.notifyDataSetChanged(); line, the vArrayAdapter_Destinations is null and I get a NULL pointer exception.

How do I fall out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two variables with the same name, one is in class scope and the other is in method scope of your `onCreate` method. 
The `ArrayAdapter` you are creating is gone after your `onCreate` method has finished. So the `onLoadFinished` method is trying to access the global variable that is still null and the exception is correct.

Assign the `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vArrayList_Destinations);` to your global variable and you should be fine.

EDIT:
To make the variable scopes clearer for you, let's look only at the scopes:

-`DestinationListActivity`
|
|-- (1) `vArrayAdapter_Destinations` (initialized to `null`) 
| 
|---- `onCreate` 
|           |
|           | ---- (2)`vArrayAdapter_Destinations` (initialized to `new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);` 
| 
|---- `onLoadFinished` 
|           | 
|           | ---- HERE is the call on the `vArrayAdapter_Destinations` from (1) because (2) is out of scope

Hope this helps you to understand your problem better.

Comment: Nice. This is the pitfall of developing along.  I could not do the array adapter initialization at the global level.  I think that was because "this" may not be available until you are in the onCreate.  So I copied the whole line into the onCreate and did not trim it down to just the assignment. 

I removed the ArrayAdapter<String> from in front of the variable in the onCreate and now am assigning the adapter to the global variable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Loaders, but I can tell that you are not falling out of scope, and if vArrayAdapter_Destinations is null, then you need to get NullPointerException when you call vArrayAdapter_Destinations.clear() right? I would take a deep look at that first. Also, when you implement a LoaderCallback, you need to implement other methods also, right? onCreateLoader and onLoaderReset, make sure they have the right implementation.

**EDIT**

Here you have this code

```
// Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
ArrayAdapter<String> vArrayAdapter_Destinations = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
     vArrayList_Destinations);
```

This has to be this

```
// Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
vArrayAdapter_Destinations = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
     vArrayList_Destinations);
```

You already have the variable, you need to just use it. If you put class name at the start it will cause a new variable to be created. This is called [variable scope](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=java%20scope).

Comment: The .clear() is on the ArrayList and not the adapter.  I do have the onCreateLoader and onLoaderRest, but my problem is not in them so I did not include them.  Since the ArrayList is created as "new ArrayList...." when it is declared, it seems to be available in the onLoadFinished.  The ArrayAdapter is not instantiated until the "new ArrayAdapter..." in the onCreate method.  I fear that it is somehow only in scope in the onCreate method.